# Modify the Save project function

Tags: blend-files, project

**[Intro]**

I'm looking for the Python function (if it exists at all) that saves the .blend file in order to modify it. If it doesn't exist - Please continue reading. I'm opened to any suggestions!

**[Reason]**

I want to expand it so that every time a .blend file is being saved, a Statistics.txt file with project info is saved along with it.

**[Workaround]**

I think the whole thing is written in C instead of Python so I can't really modify it. The workaround I came up with is every time the wm.save_mainfile() or the wm.save_as_mainfile() is being called, a custom function gets called instead. That custom function simply runs the wm.save_mainfile() and then executes the code for the Stats.txt file.

**[N/B]**

The reason I want to avoid the workaround I came up with is that this method requires modifying a number of (5-10) .py files that actually run the wm.save_mainfile() function

**[P.S]**

So, thanks to @brockmann I got my hands on this example file (written by brockmann):

```
import bpy
import os
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

bl_info = {
    "name": "Stats Add-on",
    "author": "brockmann",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 82, 0),
    "category": "System"
}


class STATS_AP_preferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    # this must match the add-on name, use '__package__'
    # when defining this in a submodule of a python package.
    bl_idname = __name__

    state: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="switch",
        default = 'ON',
        items=(
            ("ON", "on", "", 1),
            ("OFF", "off", "", 2)))

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "state", expand=True)
    

class STATS_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
        layout.prop(prefs, "state", expand=True)

@persistent
def my_save_handler(dummy):
    if bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.state == 'ON':
        stats = bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer).split("|")
        text_file = os.path.join(bpy.path.abspath("//"), "stats.txt")
        with open(text_file, mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
            myfile.write('\n'.join(stats))


classes = (
    STATS_AP_preferences,
    STATS_PT_panel
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.app.handlers.save_post.append(my_save_handler)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
    
    bpy.app.handlers.save_post.remove(my_save_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**[The new problem]**

Everything works great when I load the script and then save the project file after that. The problem is that after closing Blender and opening it some time later - the script no longer works for some reason, even though it's "ON". Any ideas why this is happening?

**[FINAL]**

Everything works great! I updated the code snipet above so that anyone could use this tamplate. Thanks again to **@brockmann** !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**application handlers**](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=save_pre#module-bpy.app.handlers), specifically [`save_post`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=save_pre#bpy.app.handlers.save_pre) or [`save_pre`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=save_pre#bpy.app.handlers.save_pre) handlers. When you're saving the file, the handler kicks in and allows to execute whatever you want *after/before* saving the file:

```
import bpy
import os

def my_save_handler(dummy):
    stats = bpy.context.scene.statistics(bpy.context.view_layer).split("|")
    text_file = os.path.join(bpy.path.abspath("//"), "stats.txt")
    with open(text_file, mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
        myfile.write('\n'.join(stats))

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.save_post.append(my_save_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.save_post.remove(my_save_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Demo above creates a file called `stats.txt` when saving the blend file:

```
Scene Collection 
 Icing 
 Verts:995,340 
 Faces:995,397 
 Tris:1,990,650 
 Objects:0/1,011 
 Memory: 593.1 MiB 
 2.93.4
```

---

Handlers are freed when loading new files by default. If you want to keep the handler alive when loading new files add the `@persistent` decorator to the handler function:

```
@persistent
def my_save_handler(dummy):
    ...
```

Further reading: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=save_pre#persistent-handler-example

Comment: Wha **_Icing_** ????... that better not be a donut.

Comment: [..finally  joined some illustrious company](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/marshal)

Comment: Pew, pew! May the force be with you @batFINGER

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129536/discussion-between-brockmann-and-aleks-k).

Comment: @brockmann any ideas?

Comment: @AleksK. Wasn't notified... Easy, just add the `@persistent` decorator to the handler. Do not forget to import it beforehand `from bpy.app.handlers import persistent`, see the docs: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=save_pre#persistent-handler-example Suggest ask a new question next time or just ping me...

Answer (score 5):

**Use the handlers.**

There are two handlers available, [`save_pre`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.save_pre) and [`save_post`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.save_post). All handlers have two arguments, the scene and the depsgraph. Since the load and save handlers are not specific to one scene, rather all, any or all of these arguments can be `None`, the case here.  *The scene argument is often named `dummy` in examples when this is the case*

The persistent decorator [`@persistent`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example) is used to keep the handler alive, should the user load a file.

Instead will iterate over all scenes and print the statistics on save.

```
import bpy

from bpy.app.handlers import persistent, save_post


def stats():
    from pathlib import Path
    fp = Path(bpy.data.filepath)
    name = fp.stem
    fp = fp.parent / f"{name}_stats.txt"
    buffer = [name]
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        buffer.append(scene.name)
        buffer.extend(
            [
                f"\t{ob.name} : {ob.type}"
                for ob in scene.objects
            ]
        )
    fp.write_text("\n".join(buffer))

@persistent
def save_handler(scene, depsgraph):
    stats()

save_post.append(save_handler)
```

Note: tried looping over scenes and producing scene stats with `scene.statistics(scene.view_layers[i])` as also outlined in [@brockmann's excellent answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237636/15543).  (added example file IO using `pathlib`) As a general rule I suggest never mix context with handlers... especially operator calls.  A detailed stats report can be gleaned from the data

[Printing a hierarchy of objects.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146344/15543)

[Finding Vertices, Edges, Faces, and Tris using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102597/finding-vertices-edges-faces-and-tris-using-python)

Sample output, blend file `snork.blend`

`snork_stats.txt`

```
snork
Scene
    Armature : ARMATURE
    Cube : MESH
    Lamp : LIGHT
    Camera : CAMERA
    Cube.001 : MESH
Scene.001
    Cube.002 : MESH
```

**Re pre and post.**

If we make a handler for both, and simply

```
def save_pre_handler(dummy):
    print("PRE", bpy.data.filepath)

def save_post_handler(dummy):
    print("POST", bpy.data.filepath)
```

On opening `snork.blend` and save,

```
Read blend: /home/batfinger/Desktop/snork.blend
PRE /home/batfinger/Desktop/snork.blend
POST /home/batfinger/Desktop/snork.blend
Info: Saved "snork.blend"
```

then save as `grunt.blend`

```
PRE /home/batfinger/Desktop/snork.blend
POST /home/batfinger/Desktop/grunt.blend
```

could generate some report (make buffer global for example) from pre handler to use in post to inform grunt was previously snork.

**Stat the file.**

There is a python script available to read data from blend files without launching blender.

[How to extract render info from a .blend file without launching Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55499/how-to-extract-render-info-from-a-blend-file-without-launching-blender)

[Is there a way to acces external .blend file's data with python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/is-there-a-way-to-acces-external-blend-files-data-with-python-script)

[How to search through multiple Blender files to find a specific object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109630/how-to-search-through-multiple-blender-files-to-find-a-specific-object)

[Iterate over CollectionProperty with blendfile.py](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62220/iterate-over-collectionproperty-with-blendfile-py)

[Manipulating .blend file text blocks with blendfile.py (CRUD)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145906/manipulating-blend-file-text-blocks-with-blendfile-py-crud)

also mentioned in links  is running blender in background mode

```
blender -b snork.py -P stats.py
```

Instead of writing file on save, could add a python or shell script to generate the info from a saved blend file.

```
blendstats snork.py
```

Comment: Very nice...... 30 seconds Mr. Holmes :D

Comment: Works in this case and is a simple demo, OP messing around with a cool C binary anyway. If you have any serious concerns, don't hesitate and suggest an edit @batFINGER.

Comment: Gotta do something to keep up brockers..