# How to edit autosave file location for (blend1, blend2, ...)

Tags: versions, system, saving

As a company we are used to save different versions of our files constantly, to be able to go back to previous steps in the process:

```
House_01_(blocking).blend
House_02_(roof).blend
House_03_(different_roof).blend
```

We need to have autosave on, in case users forget saving manually, but this totally clutters the folder with blend1, blend2,... files. of EVERY manual saved file.

```
House_01_(blocking).blend
House_01_(blocking).blend1
House_01_(blocking).blend2
House_02_(roof).blend
House_02_(roof).blend1
House_02_(roof).blend2
House_03_(different_roof).blend
House_03_(different_roof).blend1
House_03_(different_roof).blend2
```

This clutter cannot be inteded in my opinion. We cannot turn it off, as quit.blend files are stored in tmp folder, which gets wiped if the system crashes completely.

So blender developers are telling us we have to manually delete all these automatic blend1/2/3 files and are not giving us an option to change their location?

Is it possible anyone write a script or addon for this kind of problem?
Some Blender versions ago, I was able to edit the location, was this feature removed? Why?

Comment: A script in Blender should work. Here are a few examples: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/237634/107598