# How to query .blend file via command line, or python script, and extract data from it

Tags: python, command-line

I need to query the `.blend` file and extract any type of data from it. Things like:

1. does it have composition enabled?
2. what is the output file and format set by default?
3. how many frames we have and do we have any animation inside it?
4. and any other data...

Hope there is an API for all of those and more. I need to extract any data I can from CLI.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55499/how-to-extract-render-info-from-a-blend-file-without-launching-blender  run in bg mode https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-blender-python-script  build blender as a python module https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126959/how-to-build-blender-as-python-module

Comment: nice! thank you.