# What's the easiest way to open a blend file through the Python API?

Tags: python, blend-files

I am looking for the easiest way to open a `*.blend` file through the Python API. Do I need an operator for this command? Can anyone help out?

Comment: From the command line? From within Blender? What's your goal? You can use [`bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=mainfile#bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile), there is a [`blend_render_info`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55499/how-to-extract-render-info-from-a-blend-file-without-launching-blender/55503#55503) module as well as a [`blendfile.py`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2439/31447) might want to work with, you can use the command line, bpy as standalone module etc. Please edit your question and add your requirements.